# Tensorflow: Exogenous feature key raises KeyError on StructuralEnsembleRegressor predict call

Tags: time-series, tensorflow-estimator

I have a tensorflow implementation for timeseries forecasting. My data contains exogeneous features, I provide them in my train input and evaluate inputs. In the prediction step `predict_continuation_input_fn` raises KeyError for my exogenous feature column. Here is the simplified version of my code:

```py
features = (ex_0, ex_1, ex_2)
reader = tf.contrib.timeseries.CSVReader(
  _DATA_FILE,
  column_names=(tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.TIMES, tf.contrib.timeseries.TrainEvalFeatures.VALUES) + features,
  column_dtypes=(tf.int64,tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.float32),
  skip_header_lines=1)

estimator = tf.contrib.timeseries.StructuralEnsembleRegressor(
  periodicities=[20],
  num_features=1,
  exogenous_feature_columns= [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(column_name=f, dimension=1) for f in features])

train_input_fn=tf.contrib.timeseries.RandomWindowInputFn(reader, batch_size=4, window_size=100)
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=20)

evaluation_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.WholeDatasetInputFn(reader)
evaluation = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=evaluation_input_fn, steps=1)

predict_input_fn = tf.contrib.timeseries.predict_continuation_input_fn(
      evaluation, steps=100)
(predictions,) = tuple(estimator.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))
```

At this point I get error `KeyError: 'ex_0'`. Error is obvious, since resulting `evaluation` variable does not contain my exogenous features. `predict_continuation_input_fn` has argument to get exogenous_features however I could not find any documentation on how to feed exogenous data from evaluation to that argument.

How should I provide those features to prediction? Is there a flaw in my implementation? Advises are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have figured it out, but if not - you need to provide extra exogenous features corresponding to the future prediction time window (i.e. not the same as the ones you provide for training and evaluation).

See here for an example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/timeseries/examples/known_anomaly.py#L126